# function as argument on evaluate method on google puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to run a function inside evaluate(), I'm passing it as an argument, but I'm getting **'func is not a function'**, what am I missing?

Puppeteer version: 10.2

Platform / OS version: Windows 10, Node 8.2.1

```
var func = function() {
   console.log("xxxxx");
};

var response = await page.evaluate( (func) => {
   func(); //func is not a function
}, func);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`page.exposeFunction(name, puppeteerFunction)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction):

```
await page.exposeFunction("add", (a, b) => a + b);
const response = await page.evaluate(() => {
   return window.add(2, 2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, puppeteer has to marshal the code in your evaluate function ultimately as a string and inject it into to page context.  You can't pass function references or anything non-serializable across that boundary.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, indeed I had to change that and query for a more general DOM element and then run the function outside page.evalute()